# Discord.py Voice channel renames too long

Tags: discord.py

I have a code:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_update(before, after):
    if before.name == "a" and before.category is None:
        await after.edit(name=before.name)
```

In theory, it should check if the channel was renamed with the name "a" and if it was renamed, its name should remain the same, that is, "a". The problem is that the channel is renamed only after 5 minutes, or it is not renamed at all. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: The ratelimit for editing a channel is 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel, there’s no way of bypassing this

Comment: I'm interested by this @ŁukaszKwieciński, are there some references for what you are saying ? I'd like to learn more about that